# method that takes a string, in this format "aabbaadddc". Encode the string by counting the consecutive letters. Ex: "a2b2a2d3c1"

Tags: c

I have written a code but i am not able to get the desired output. I am doing some mistake, but unable to trace what exactly it is.
Below is my code.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    char c[] = "aabbaadddc",*ptr = c,prev,t[10],*tptr = t;
    int i,j,count = 0;
    while(*ptr != '\0') {
        prev = *ptr;
        count = 0;
        while(*ptr == prev) {
            count++;
            ptr++;
        }
        *tptr = prev;
        tptr++;
        *tptr = (char)count;
        tptr++;
    }
    *tptr = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", t);
    return 0;
}
```

I am expecting "a2b2a2d3c1" in the t string. I want to know my mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change 17th line to

```
*tptr = (char)(count + '0');
```

to add ASCII value of `0` to your counter.

But i would change the code because it has several problem:

- if we have `abcde` (`strlen = 5`) string the result string should be `a1b1c1d1e1` (`strlen = 10`). So we get buffer overflow
- if some char occurs more then 10 times we get incorrect result string

To make this algorithms right i would use another buffer with enough size to store all values and add values (chars and numbers) there. To convert `int` to `char[]` use `itoa` or `snprintf`.

Comment: yes if character occurs more than 10 times we get incorrect result, whats the reason ?

Comment: @Megharaj Because you deal with chars. To write number `10` you have to write 2 chars. Actually it depends on your task. If you know that it will never happens just allocate char array big enough to store all new characters. If you need to write safe function you look my updates.

Answer (score 2):

From what I see

```
*tptr = prev;
 tptr++;
 *tptr = (char)count;
```

is the mistake.

It should be

```
*tptr = count+48;
```

I am not sure how you are going to manage double digit numbers with this algorithm.I would suggest you look at the `sprintf` function.It would be helpful in your case.

Answer (score 1):

t is too short - is has no room for the terminating \x00!

Furthermore, you're inserting a character \x02 (from the counter), not '2'. That means you would need to add '0' in order to get the right output:

```
*tptr = (char)count + '0';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    char c[] = "aabbaadddc",*ptr = c,prev;
    char t[10];                                // t is too small - there is no room for the string terminator
    char *tptr = t;
    int i,j,count = 0;
    while(*ptr != '\0') {
        prev = *ptr;
        count = 0;
        while(*ptr == prev) {
            count++;
            ptr++;
        }
        *tptr = prev; 
        tptr++;
        *tptr = (char)count;   // You need to add the ascii value for 0
        tptr++;
    }
    *tptr = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", t);
    return 0;
}
```

Some notes and observations:

Your code is not very general. The encoding should be in a function and main should hold the code to test the function (calling it and printing the result).

Your code can only handle up to 9 consecutive letters.

The encoding algorithm isn't reversible if the source string contains digits.